# How can I get the ASP.NET Core environment in a static helper method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I can't use dependency injection, I have static helper class with static methods in my ASP.NET Core project. What is the easiest way to determine that app is running in development environment?

Equivalent of:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) // -> this env is what I'm looking for
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I get `env` manually without DI?

Comment: Why do you have them defined as static methods? Why don't you make them non-static, and construct their class using IoC container?

Comment: For reasons outside of scope of this question. It is large project, they just are static methods in helper class. That is the reality.

Comment: Is there a reason you can not create non-static class for this?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the Startup is the very first thing that runs on an ASP.NET Core application (after the host is built in the main Program class), there are very simple solutions available:

```cs
public class Startup 
{
    public static IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Environment = environment;
    }
}
```

---

Note that the correct solution is, however, not to mix Dependency Injection with static classes.